# Replace Action bar with toolbar

Tags: android, exception, replace, android-actionbar, android-toolbar

I'm using a Toolbar to replace the ActionBar. All is going well before replacing.
after replacing it gives me error:

`java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.oi.mmg/com.oi.mmg.EventDetailsScreenActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException:`

This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request **Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false** in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.

Comment: here is some pieces of the code:

Comment: here is some pieces of the code: @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_event_details_layout);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_group_profile);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
toolbar.setBackgroundDrawable(newColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.bluecolor)));
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
 getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);  }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing your code I would suggest using this parent theme for your application:

```
Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar
```

The property "windowActionBar" is then "false" by default.

And if you are using AppCompat your activities should then extend from "AppCompatActivity".

Answer (score 2):

In the style used by your Activity you have to add:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    .....
    <!-- Both of these are needed -->
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```